# How to launch default web browser on second screen

Tags: c#, wpf, process, screen

I have an application that gets instructions and one of the instructions is to open a website with given url.
the url can be opened on main screen or on second screen (depend on parameter).

I have this method to get the second screen:

```
protected Screen GetSecondaryScreen()
{
   return Screen.AllScreens.Where(x => !x.Primary).First();
}
```

I have this code that initialized the browser arguments:
browserNameApplication - can be chrome/iexplorer/msedge eg.

```
public void Init(string browserNameApplication)
{
  _browserApplication = browserNameApplication;
  AddAdditionalArguments();
}

private void AddAdditionalArguments()
{
   var secondaryScreen = GetSecondaryScreen();
   if (secondaryScreen != null)
   {
      _browserArguments += "--kiosk " " +$"--window-position={secondaryScreen.WorkingArea.Top},{secondaryScreen.WorkingArea.Left}";
   }
}
```

I have this code that open the browser and called after the Init:

```
public void OpenBrowser(string Url)
{
   Process browserProcess = new Process();
   browserProcess.StartInfo.FileName = string.Concat(_browserApplication, FileExtension);
   browserProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Concat(_browserArguments, $" {Url} ");
   browserProcess.Start();
}
```

also tried the arguments to be with --new-window and it doesn't worked.
the secondaryScreen is initialized by the GetSecondaryScreen() method.

for the first web browser i want to open, it works fine and open it on secondary screen/primary.
In the second request I'm getting (can be with diff url off course), the browser opens on the same screen the previous request was opened even if I told him different.

for example:
first request i'm getting:
url: [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)
open on screen: primary
actual result: [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) was opened on primary screen.

first request i'm getting:
url: [www.cnn.com](http://www.cnn.com)
open on screen: sceond
actual result: [www.cnn.com](http://www.cnn.com) was opened on primary screen.

how can I open the second request that opens url on the second screen?